# How to make visualstudio .net work with VB6 and service pack 6

Tags: visual-studio

I have VB application that requires visual service pack 6 to run , now when I install visualstudio.net (any version of .net)  Its debugger doesn't work properly ,I am able to create windows/web application in visualstudio.net but not able to debug anything  , so I have to keep 2 computers , one for VB and one for .net , does anybody have any idea what is the cause for this and is there any fix for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used visual studio 6 and visual studio 2005 on the same system, so I know you can set it up so that both debuggers work.  However, when I did it the setup just worked, so I can't tell you what I did to make it work, except that VS2005 was on the machine first.

Comment: I also have tried VB6 and VS2005 on same machine without problem but my this VB6 requires service pack 6 and VS debugger is not working with visual service pack 6 , any idea ?

Comment: I have installed VB6 with SP6 and VS 2005 and VS 2008 on many machines and never had a problem.  There must be some third party at work here sabotaging your system.  Some other app, drivers, bad hardware, etc.